# Can you safely call "getDrawable" or "decodeResource" on the UI thread in Android

Tags: android

Is it bad practice to call

`getResources().getDrawable()` or `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`

from the UI thread on Android? I'm just wondering since I have this situation where I want to show a loding image in my view while I execute a background operation, but Im still calling either one of the above methods... almost every project I look at seems to execute either method on any thread without second thought, but I'm just looking for best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Fast forward 3 years since I asked this question, and I think the *short* answer is "Just use Picasso or Glide". I think the *long* answer is "it depends". It depends on the size of the Image/drawable. For `BitmapFactory#decodeResource`, you should do everything you can to stay off the main thread. If I'm trying to show a placeholder image, best practice is that it should be packaged in your app with a reasonable size with fits with your design.

Answer (score 0):

It will be good practice if you do any GUI updates on UI thread. Inside any thread you can run your UI thread where you can do the UI stuffs or else you can go for message handler also which will do the same for you.

```
Runnable run_in_ui = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do your UI stuffs here
        }
    };
    runOnUiThread(run_in_ui);
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that its best practice to update UI components on the UI thread. I'm more interested in knowing if getDrawable() and decodeResource() are considered "I/O" on the UI thread? or if they should ALWAYS be done on a worker thread?

Answer (score 0):

Even though Vijay Sharma suggested using Picasso, I would suggest you using frescolib from Facebook. It does all possible optimizations starting from Hardware Caching ending up modifying Http requests with Pipelining concept.

Instead of doing it on your own, it is better to rely on Facebook team's work:

build.gradle:

```
 dependencies {
   // your app's other dependencies
   compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.7.0+'
 }
```

view.xml:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"
    <!-- other attributes -->
```

java:

```
 mSimpleDraweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

That simple!

Comment: Yes, Fresco also. I was just trying to convey that I think using a library vs doing it yourself was the way to go.